Helium balloons at party gives criminal away
I'm looking for the name of a movie with the following plot ingredients:

a criminal (murderer?) is almost getting away with his/her (not sure) crime
somehow, a bunch of helium balloons (kites?) at a kids party give him/her away in the final scenes
recentish (~made in last 10 years)
definitely Hollywood movie

Couldn't find anything in IMDB advanced search or on Netflix.
UPDATE: after more extensive IMDB/Wikipedia searching, I'm no longer convinced it's a move, but that it might possibly be an episode of a TV series (detective).

@Richard that was my first guess, but I can't find that scene in the ebook, and not in the movie either (fast-scrolled on Netflix). But now that I think of it, I vague remember that I had read the balloon scene in a book when watching the movie. So it's likely a book adaption.

@Richard omg, I just realized that I got the book The Fifth Witness a month after I saw the Lincoln Lawyer in a movie theatre. I must have visualized the book with images of Matthew McConaughey and convinced myself that it had already been adapted! If you answer, I'll accept.
